# JSON schema without "properties" keyword

Tags: json, jsonschema

Vendor send me a json schema. Please look at this:

```
{
  "$schema" : "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type" : "object",
  "definitions" : {
    ...
  },
  "oneOf" : [{
      "$ref" : "#/definitions/commons/strings/text"
    }, {
      "$ref" : "#/definitions/dto/scriptStep"
    }, {
      "$ref" : "#/definitions/dto/callResult"
    }
  ]
}
```

There is no "properties" keyword (but by the way there is very large "definitions" part). Does it mean that schema actually descibes empty json object {}? Or does it mean that json could contain one of elements from "oneOf" array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All JSON Schema keywords are constraints.  For example, the empty schema `{}` means that any JSON is valid.  A schema with just `{ "type": "object" } mean that any JSON object is valid.  There are no constraints on what properties the object has.

However, that isn't what your vendor is expressing in this schema.  The JSON doesn't only have to be valid against the `"type": "object"`, but also against one of the three schemas referenced in `oneOf`.  Presumably, those schemas include a `properties` keyword.

This probably isn't the best designed schema, but it is valid.